# What will be the best way to create a temporary text file for bash output processing and delete the file after the process ends

Tags: bash

I am trying to find the proper solution to delete the temporary file that I used to get the result of SELECT query of sqlplus using bash. As I can not create the desired output file as per the format, I first store the result in a file and then process it and append it to the target file. How should I name the temp file inorder to delete the exact file of the current bash process? I even named the temp file by appending the process id name, but the processes are so many that the same process id file can be created at the same time.

```
SQL_FILE=/sql/transaction.sql

#Create tep
Pid=$$
TEMP_FILE=${TEMP_FILE_PATH}/output_$Pid.txt

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus ${ORA_USER}/${ORA_PASS}@${SQL_PLUS_IP}:${SQL_PLUS_PORT}/${ORA_SID} @${SQL_FILE} ${TEMP_FILE}

#After Processing
rm -f ${TEMP_FILE}

exit 0
```

The output_$Pid.txt temp file is used to spool the output of the sql query,.

Comment: After creating the temporary file set a `trap`, e.g. `trap 'rm -f "$tempfile"' SIGTERM SIGINT EXIT` so that the temporary file is remove when the script is terminated, interrupted or exits.

Comment: Read [How do I create a temporary file in a secure manner?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/062).

Comment: See the `trap` command (in the bash man-page listed under _SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS_). You can register a trap which fires whenever your script exits, be it in the normal way or by a signal. In such a trap, you could remove the temporary file. However, there are signals which can not be trapped, so it is not 100% certain that the file will be removed in any conceivable case.

Comment: Thank you @DavidC.Rankin @M. Nejat Aydin @user1934428 will use the `trap` command to delete the file on normal or abnormal termination with @Iavn solution to create the file with `$(mktemp)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comment, in addition to creating the temporary file and setting a `trap` to remove the temp file on termination, interrupt or exit, you should validate each step along the way. You should validate `mktemp` provides a zero exit code. You should validate that the temp file is in fact created. Then you can use the temp file with confidence that no intervening error took place.

A short example would be:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

tmpfile=$(mktemp)       ## create temporary file

[ "$?" -eq 0 ] || {     ## validate zero exit code from mktemp
    printf "error: mktemp had non-zero exit code.\n" >&2
    exit 1
}

[ -f "$tmpfile" ] || {  ## validate temp file actually created
    printf "error: tempfile does not exist.\n" >&2
    exit 1
}

## set trap to remove temp file on termination, interrupt or exit
trap 'rm -f "$tmpfile"' SIGTERM SIGINT EXIT

## Your Script Content Goes Here, below simply exercises the temp file as an example

## fill temp file with heredoc to test
cat > "$tmpfile" << eof
The temporary file was successfully create at: '$tmpfile'.
The temporary file will be removed by a trap function when this
script is terminated or interrupted, or when this script exits
normally.
eof

cat "$tmpfile"          ## output temp file to terminal
```

There are several ways to approach this. This is just a plain-Jane, non-exiting way to put the pieces together and the validations to ensure it all happens as you intend.

Answer (score 1):

there is a special command for this `mktemp`, usage:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
echo 'some data' >> "$tmp"
cat  "$tmp"
rm   "$tmp"
```

Answer (score 0):

use a uuid generator to generate a unique id, like the [uuidgen](https://man.archlinux.org/man/uuidgen.1.en).